# How can I display only one section at a time while scrolling vertically on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I am trying to create an effect on a blog page in which the blog posts are displayed as cards, and whenever one scrolls vertically on the page, a card will fade into view and then fade out when the next card is displayed. Something similar to a carousel/image slider but where only one card is visible at the time. At the same time I want the background image to be fixed. A mix between parallax and carousel.

I have tried to set the cards' container to allow overflow-y so that the cards are scrollable, but I do not want the scrollbar to appear either. Honestly, I have looked everywhere for a similar example, but none are close to what I am trying to achieve.

I have found other examples where I can create a parallax effect, but the thing is I only have one background image. I am not sure if I need to use JavaScript as well to try to implement this design. The closest I have come to is [ScrollOut](https://scroll-out.github.io/), but I do not know how to make only one card visible at the time.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/gercamjr/pen/yLzNbmq)

```
<header>
  <div class="logo">

  </div>
  <div class="title" id='title'>
    <h1 data-scroll>One Star Thoughts</h1>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <div class="hamburger">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="/" class="login-button">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id='stars'></div>
<div id='stars2'></div>
<div id='stars3'></div>

<section class="section__posts">

  <div class="section__posts--card">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/780x200" class="blog-image" alt="">
    <h1 class="blog-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h1>
    <p class="blog-overview">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt incidunt fugiat quos porro repellat harum. Adipisci tempora corporis rem cum.</p>
    <a href="/" class="btn dark">read</a>
  </div>

  <div class="section__posts--card">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/780x200" class="blog-image" alt="">
    <h1 class="blog-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h1>
    <p class="blog-overview">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt incidunt fugiat quos porro repellat harum. Adipisci tempora corporis rem cum.</p>
    <a href="/" class="btn dark">read</a>
  </div>

  <div class="section__posts--card">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/780x200" class="blog-image" alt="">
    <h1 class="blog-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h1>
    <p class="blog-overview">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt incidunt fugiat quos porro repellat harum. Adipisci tempora corporis rem cum.</p>
    <a href="/" class="btn dark">read</a>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Here is sort of what I want to do, but I only want one card visible in the view port at a time: [link](https://codepen.io/notoriousb1t/pen/zLbVEW)

Comment: If a card is too tall to fit in the viewport I assume you'll want the user to be able to scroll down to see the bottom part. Then if the user scrolls a bit more does the next card immediately occupy the viewport? Is there a big gap so the user doesn't have to be too accurate scrolling down to see the bottom of the fiirst card?

Comment: My aim is to make each card the same width and height so as to not worry about the card being too tall. Also, I am not so much worried about the gap. What I am trying to do is get only one card to appear at a time, but in order for them to appear and disappear, the user has to vertically scroll down or up, and at the same time the background is fixed. So the scrolling is only for the cards to appear and disappear.

Comment: A user can set the viewport to be what they want (on a laptop/desktop) or can have a very narrow device in landscape mode so I don't understand how you wont need to scroll the card to see the bottom of it. Then, at what point does the system decide to overlay it with the next card?

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I had not thought about that. So I will have to change the approach then. What if I had the cards all stacked one on top of each other, then when a user scrolls the cards are displayed one after the other? Like a deck of playing cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to organicon's insight about `IntersectionObserver` I was able to come up with a solution that created the effect exactly as I wanted.

- I made the background fixed and turned off `overflow` for the body.
- I wrapped the cards in a container, and turned on the `overflow-y` BUT I hid the scrollbar using: `scrollbar-width: none; -ms-overflow-style:none;`
- Wrote a script using `IntersectionObserver` that will track when a card comes into view. When the card appears a CSS animation is applied that fades the card in.

```js
const callback = (entries) => {
    entries.forEach(
        (entry) => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                console.log("the element is intersecting");
                entry.target.style.animation = entry.target.dataset.fade;
                entry.target.style.opacity = 1;
            } else {
                entry.target.style.animation = "none";
                entry.target.style.opacity = 0;
            }
        }
    );
}
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);

const fadeItems = document.querySelectorAll('.animate');
    fadeItems.forEach(item => {
        console.log("adding " + fadeItems.length + " cards to the observer");
        observer.observe(item)
    });
```

```css
:root {
    --ff-primary: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    --ff-secondary: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    --fw-reg: 300;
    --fw-bold: 900;
    --clr-light: #fff;
    --clr-dark: #303030;
    --clr-grey: lightgrey;
    --clr-accent: #16e0bd;
    --clr-danger: tomato;
    --fs-h1: 3rem;
    --fs-h2: 2.25rem;
    --fs-h3: 1.25rem;
    --fs-body: 1rem;
    --bs: 0.25em 0.25em 0.75em rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), 0.125em 0.125em 0.25em rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
     :root {
        --fs-h1: 4.5rem;
        --fs-h2: 3.75rem;
        --fs-h3: 1.5rem;
        --fs-body: 1.125rem;
    }
}

html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    font-family: var(--ff-primary);
    font-size: var(--fs-body);
    line-height: 1.6;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #1b2735 0%, #090a0f 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

strong {
    font-weight: var(--fw-bold)
}

:focus {
    outline: 3px solid var(--clr-accent);
    outline-offset: 3px;
}

/* wrapper */

.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


/* header */

header {
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    
}

nav {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: var(--clr-light);
    border-radius: 2em;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 10;
}

/*Styling Links*/

.nav-links {
  color: var(--clr-light);
  display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    width: 88vw;
    padding: 0 0.7vw;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-links li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 0.7vw;
}

.nav-links li a:hover {
    color: #61DAFB;
}

.nav-links li {
    position: relative;
}

.nav-links li a::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #61DAFB;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
    margin: 0 0 0 10%;
}

.nav-links li a:hover::before {
    width: 80%;
}

.login-button {
    color: var(--clr-light);
    padding: 0.6rem 0.8rem;
    margin-left: 2vw;
    font-size: 1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.login-button:hover {
    color: var(--clr-dark);
    background-color: #000;
    transition: all ease-in-out 350ms;
}
* site title */

.title h1 {
    margin: 1em auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: transparent;
}

@supports(-webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--clr-light)) {
    .title h1 {
        color: transparent;
        -webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--clr-light);
        text-shadow: none;
    }
}

/* section posts */

.posts {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    /* Firefox */
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
}

.posts::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.post__card {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 40rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin: 15rem auto;
    background: var(--clr-light);
    border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.post__card:first-child {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.post__card:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 22rem;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.blog-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.blog-title {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: -6px;
}

.blog-overview {
    margin: 10px 0 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.section__posts--card--button {
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.btn.dark {
    background: var(--clr-dark);
    color: var(--clr-light);
}

.btn.grey {
    background: var(--clr-grey);
    color: var(--clr-dark);
}

.btn.danger {
    background: var(--clr-danger);
    color: var(--clr-dark);
}

@media (max-width: 600x) {
    .posts {
        padding: 2.4rem;
    }
    .section__posts--card {
        padding: 2.4rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='stars'></div>
  <div class="stars2"></div>
  <div class='stars3'></div>
  <header>
    
    <div class="title" id='title'>
      <h1>One Star Thoughts</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="hamburger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#" class="login-button">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="login-button" href="#">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="posts">

    <div class="post__card animate" data-fade="fade-in 2s">
      <div class="post__wrapper">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/780x200" class="blog-image" alt="">
        <h1 class="blog-title">Blog title + '...'}</h1>
        <p class="blog-overview">This is the blog post test stuff and stuff and stuff and stuff + '...'}</p>
        <a href="#" class="section__posts--card--button btn dark">read</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="post__card animate" data-fade="fade-in 2s">
      <div class="post__wrapper">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/780x200" class="blog-image" alt="">
        <h1 class="blog-title">Blog title + '...'}</h1>
        <p class="blog-overview">This is the blog post test stuff and stuff and stuff and stuff + '...'}</p>
        <a href="#" class="section__posts--card--button btn dark">read</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="post__card animate" data-fade="fade-in 2s">
      <div class="post__wrapper">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/780x200" class="blog-image" alt="">
        <h1 class="blog-title">Blog title + '...'}</h1>
        <p class="blog-overview">This is the blog post test stuff and stuff and stuff and stuff + '...'}</p>
        <a href="#" class="section__posts--card--button btn dark">read</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="post__card animate" data-fade="fade-in 2s">
      <div class="post__wrapper">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/780x200" class="blog-image" alt="">
        <h1 class="blog-title">Blog title + '...'}</h1>
        <p class="blog-overview">This is the blog post test stuff and stuff and stuff and stuff + '...'}</p>
        <a href="#" class="section__posts--card--button btn dark">read</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're going for, you could use `position: sticky` along with an `IntersectionObserver` to create fade-in/fade-out effects.

A basic implementation of a position: sticky layout could be something like this:

```
<div class="section__posts--card">
    <!-- ****   add inner wrapper  **** -->
    <div class="inner-el">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/780x200" class="blog-image" alt="">
      <h1 class="blog-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h1>
      <p class="blog-overview">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt incidunt fugiat quos porro repellat harum. Adipisci tempora corporis rem cum.</p>
      <a href="/" class="btn dark">read</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.section__posts {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.section__posts--card {
  height: 200vh; // how far the user should scroll before content changes
}

.inner-el {
  top: 200px; // how far from the top of the viewport the content should sit
  height: auto;
  position: sticky;
  width: 75vw;
  max-width: 50rem;
  margin: auto;
}
```

This is a pretty good 'tutorial' on how to add `IntersectionObserver` with `position: sticky`: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/sticky-headers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This made my blog cards fill up the whole page, which is not exactly what I want. The card should appear and disappear upon scrolling.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the position: sticky approach is what you want.  Do you have a pen with your attempt to use the sticky position?  You may want to check out this description of how it can be implemented: https://elad.medium.com/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46

Comment: There is a link to the codepen I have setup for this project. It is in my original question.

Comment: If you add the `.inner-el` divs inside the `.section__posts--card` elements, add the `height: 200vh(or whatever)` rule to `.section__posts--card`, and change the `overflow: hidden` to `overflow-x: hidden` it seems to work.  Of course it will take some tweaking to fix your background, but that should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yes you are right,. I made these changes and it behaves the way you said. But I am having trouble getting the background to remain fixed. Is this where parallax scrolling could come in? I would not know how to do this.

Comment: I want to make the blog cards to scroll without making the whole page scroll, does that make sense?

Comment: You could wrap the background els in a div and set that to `position: fixed; height: 100vh; width: 100vw; top: 0; left: 0;`.